# Using Google Chrome as default image viewer

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, file-association

How do I set Google Chrome as the default application for PNG files?

Chrome version: 58.0.3029.96
Operating system: Windows 10 Pro 64-bit

Comment: Why would you set your browser to the default viewer? As for [how](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-change-file-associations-in-windows-2624477): Check the default programs dialog(s) and options.

Comment: You could try right clicking on a .PNG file, click open with then choose default program, if Google Chrome is not on the list click on browse and search for Chrome and select it??

Comment: @Seth: Because the built-in photo app is crap.

Comment: So you use a Browser? Which is meant to display Websites? Why not use an alternative like [FastStone ImageViewer](http://www.faststone.org/), [IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.com/) or one of the [many alternatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_image_viewers) which are meant to display graphics? In addition, why is it only a bad choice for PNG?

Comment: I'm trying to just view a graphics file (.jpg, gif, .png) using Chrome Win10, but without making it the default. Right clicking and Open with Chrome as an option worked great in Win7, not Win10.  Wish someone actually knew the answer and gave a step-by-step example.

Comment: Self answer and mark question as answered pls.

Comment: @Seth A browser, which is meant to display many types of media in a trusted, sandboxed, cross-platform environment with no additional installs.

Answer (score 1):

Windows blocks it as a default option, you have to: right click on the image file > open with > choose another app > scroll down > more apps > scroll down > choose another app on this computer > For me I went to the main windows C:program files(x86)/Google/ and then you go into the chrome folder and select the executable file for it

Comment: This worked for me, except my executable was at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

Answer (score -2):

Right click on it and do a file association, select another programs, and make it permanent by checking the "always" tick on.